# CI CD pipeline Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build CI CD Pipeline For Our project.
when my application start Building.
we are getting issue.

[image: error]

### [error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.104\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(141,5): Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "D:\a\1\s\src\VTTDemo.Web.Host\wwwroot\dist\101.7d2715da89efeae8b0da.js" because it was not found.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.104\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(141,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "D:\a\1\s\src\VTTDemo.Web.Host\wwwroot\dist\101.7d2715da89efeae8b0da.js" because it was not found. [D:\a\1\s\src\VTTDemo.Web.Host\VTTDemo.Web.Host.csproj]

step has follow.
1. Configure Cd From Solution explorer 
2. Enter App, Azure Login
3. Select Project and Pipeline 
4. Edit Pipeline 
5. Save and queue Pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with solution on GitHub - https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/162

**Solution code**

Need to add the following code in csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="node_modules\**\*;Client\**\*" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\dist\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="RunWebpack" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish">
    <Exec Command="npm run clean:dist" />
    <Exec Command="npm run build:prod" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="wwwroot\dist\**\*" />
      <Content Include="@(DistFiles)" CopytoPublishDirectory="Always" />
      <ContentWithTargetPath Include="@(DistFiles)" TargetPath="%(Identity)" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```